# InMemoryDbContext doesn't persist after seed, collection in controller always empty

Tags: c#, .net, testing, .net-core

Inside TestStartup I'm overriding ConfigureDatabase method so I can use InMemory for my tests.

```
public class TestStartup : Startup
{
    public override void ConfigureDb(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<CarContext>(options => options.UseInMemoryDatabase(Guid.NewGuid().ToString()));
        services.AddTransient<DbSeeder>();
    }
    public override void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            base.Configure(app, env);
            using (var serviceScope = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
            {
                var dbSeeder = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<DbSeed>();
                dbSeeder.Seed();
            }
        }
}

public class DbSeed
{
    private readonly CarContext _context;

    public DbSeed(ContactContext context)
    {
       _context = context;
    }

    public void Seed()
    {
        _context.Cars.AddRange(DataGenerator.Cars);
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
 }
```

Inside DbSeed class `_context.SaveChanges` saves the data (it returns > 0 in debug) 
yet in the `Controller ICarService` (which uses `CarContext`) have empty collection of Car DbSet (InMemoryDbContext is used).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that by giving the context always a new name (`Guid.NewGuid().ToString()`) you never get the same database twice. For one test you should make sure to always use the context with the same name.

This can be done e. g. the following way:

```
public override void ConfigureDb(IServiceCollection services)
{
    var dbName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    services.AddDbContext<CarContext>(options => options.UseInMemoryDatabase(dbName));
    services.AddTransient<DbSeeder>();
}
```

This way each test will get its own context, but during that test the context will always relate to the same database.